# Swift: How can I turn a NSView 45 degrees?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview

I want to show my object, after drawing inner components, rolled to an angle of 45 degrees.  How can I achieve this easily?

The object is drawn with a sub-class of a `NSView`.  It incorporates multiple `NSBezierPath` and fill, to include arcs etc.  Then the same object is used a few times at different rotated positions - *not animated!*

I use the `NSView.rotate(byDegrees:)` method, but it only seems to work for factors of 90 degrees - other angles seem to scale and omit curves (strange results).

You probably don't need code, but here's the object:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    wantsLayer = true
    layer?.masksToBounds = false
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current!.cgContext
    let path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: dirtyRect)
    NSColor.red.setFill()
    path.fill()
}
```

then:

```
let object = MyObject(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view.addSubView(object)
object.rotate(byDegrees: 23)
```

I want see many `MyObject`s, each turned a different amount.
How can I do that easily?